# I am trying to associate checkbox to inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a table where i have checkboxes for each Item on the table and these checkboxes have input attached to them, now I want that anytime a checkbox is clicked it should show the input field and I want to capture both the checkbox and the input field data

```
 <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" name="requisitions[]" value="{{ $mainStore->id }}" id="requisition-{{ $mainStore->id }}" class="form-check-input requisition-checkbox" style="display: none;" />
   <input type="text" name="quantities[]" class="requisition-quantity form-control" style="display: none;">
   <input type="hidden" name="inventoryable_type" value="{{ $mainStore }}">
</div>
```

```
   requisitionCheckboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
             var index = checkbox.value; // Get the value of the checkbox
             var quantityInput = document.getElementById('requisition-quantity-' + index);
             if (checkbox.checked) {
                 quantityInput.style.display = 'block';
                 checkbox.quantityInput = quantityInput;
                  } else {
                        quantityInput.style.display = 'none';
                        checkbox.quantityInput = null;
                    }
                    toggleRequisitionButtonVisibility(); // Toggle requisition button visibility
                });
      });
```

Then on the backend I want to capture the data

```
 protected function filterSelectedRequisitions(array $data)
    {
        $quantities = $data['quantities'];
        $requisitions = $data['requisitions'];

        $selectedRequisitions = [];
        foreach ($requisitions as $key => $requisitionId) {
            // Check if the requisition exists and has a corresponding quantity
            if (isset($quantities[$key]) && $quantities[$key] !== null) {
                // Add the requisition and its quantity to the selectedRequisitions array
                $selectedRequisitions[] = [
                    'inventory_id' => $requisitionId,
                    'quantity' => $quantities[$key]
                ];
            }
        }
    
        return $selectedRequisitions;
    }
```

However this is only working for the first item in the table but returning null for the remaining items. I want that if any checkbox is cliicked it should the quantity for that item checked.

Comment: first, is you js working ? (there is no id on the input in your example). Second you can avoid a lot of troubles and ignore the checkboxes in the backend using the input name `<input type="text" name="quantities[{{ $mainStore->id }}]">` that way you have the storeId (key) and quantity(value) in the same table

Comment: yes the javascript is working, and with this I'm getting Undefined array key 0

Comment: You dont loop `$requisitions` you loop directly `foreach ($quantities as $storeId => $qty)` simpler. if you are getting all the input and not only the shown one then in the JS do hidden+disabled